# PHP file_put_contents() error

Tags: php

Everytime I try to modify a file, I get this error and I don't know what it means:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_put_contents() [function.file-put-contents]: Only 0 of 19463 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space

Filename: Template/String.php

Line Number: 369
```

I tried looking for solutions and so far none of them made sense, well, in my opinion.

Any thoughts? A little help here please. Thank you very much.

Comment: So `possibly out of free disk space` doesn't apply? You've checked and you're 100% sure?

Comment: Have you checked folder permissions?

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question but it comes up when Googling for the error message.  Here is another possible cause for this error message.

The ext2/3/4 filesystems can reserve disk space for root.  Often it is 5% of the drive.  df shows the drive is not entirely used.  Root can write to the drive.  Non-root users will only be able to create files but not write any data to them.  See dumpe2fs and tune2fs for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This probably means that PHP is able to get a valid file descriptor, but is hitting a wall (such as a quota, sticky bit, etc) when actually trying to write the data.

It is also conceivable that you are writing (perhaps unwittingly) to a network file system that is having a problem with its peer.

More information regarding your platform would help (I've seen SELinux do strange things when improperly configured), but I think you get the gist of what to check.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a permission to where you wanted to save the content, e.g. readonly or just like the error itself, no disk space.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to increase the quota for that user on the server. You can confirm this by deleting a file and seeing if it will let you re-upload that file, but nothing further.

If you have Webmin, go to System > Disk Quota. (For a detailed explanation, see [this wiki](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/DiskQuotas).)

If you do not have Webmin or a similar interface, you will need to look up how to manually edit the user quota settings depending on which Linux distro you are using.

If you do not have access to the server you will need to contact the person who does and ask what your disk quota is and if it can be increased.

Answer (score 1):

For me I was also having the same set of errors on my login page. While exploring I found that the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file has grown up to the size of 24G. And clearing it solved the issue. To find out the size of directory use linux command `du -sh *` or `du -sh <filename>` . To clear up the log file using truncate command is the best option. Because oping with vim and deleting could be difficult because of Heavy size of the file. For truncating use the command `truncate -s 0 <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

I went to the root directory

```
cd /
```

and searched for the  folder that had the biggest space usage with

```
du -sh *
```

from there I was able to trace the file giving the headache, pluto.log in /var/log. this could be any file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a previous lock on your target file, try to:

```
$fp = fopen('yourfile.etc', 'r+');
if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    //this file is actually being used from another script / user, that's the problem.
} else {
    //ok, there wasn't lock on it, must be something else
    fclose($fp);
}
```