# Laravel 5.1: ErrorException in file_put_contents() error,possibly out of free disk space

Tags: php, laravel, disk, laravel-5.1, diskspace

This error arrived all out of a sudden.

ErrorException in D:\xampp\htdocs\pckg\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php line 81:
file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 3520 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space

Comment: check permission of /storage directory and set it to 777

Comment: Yeah I checked it. That wasn't an issue. Thanks :-)

Comment: @D.P. please mention **`full stack trace`** in your question

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA - sorry, I don't have it right now .

Comment: This answer was what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593799/151503 (even though your disk isn't full, some disk space might be reserved.)

Answer (score 14):

I just freed / cleared the `laravel.log` file in the `storage/logs` folder.

Also clearing `cache`& `sessions` folders in `storage/framework` folder can help.

It just cleared the error and the login page was loaded again !

Comment: That seems to be a temporary solution

Comment: How to stop log file creation?

Answer (score 6):

The main issue is laravel.log file. For me the file size has grown upto 24G, clearing the file made everything fine.

Use command `sudo truncate -s 0 <filename>` to clear it.

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing Composer's cache by running `composer clear-cache`

Answer (score 2):

This is because your server HDD is full or almost Full.

Check by this  command

```
df -h
```

This will show the stats.
figure out where you are storing large chunk of files and delete them.

clear the following folders in laravel project folder

```
rm -rf storage/framework/cache/
// this will logout presently logged in users
rm -rf storage/framework/sessions/
rm -rf storage/framework/sessions/views/
```

freeup this file

```
> storage/logs/laravel.log
```

you need to clear the cache by running this command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

General / permanent for this is to increase the disk space of the system.
or making the cron job to clear the laravel log file at every certain period of time.

Comment: this did not work for me... only created more errors

Comment: when I removed all of these sessions, it then could not find any so I had to flush all my cache to start from scratch which I think you should add in your answer. If the user does not flush their cache they will get errors can't the laravel app cannot find session variables inside these directories.

Answer (score 1):

My problem solve by below.

1. clear all log from storage folder.
2. Running below artisan command.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because there is no space on your server. When you will clean server storage it will be fixed.

Comment: This (old) question already contains multiple answers. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue clearing cache helps

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

do these to clear cache,views and config

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
```