# file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 178 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space?

Tags: php, laravel

Why am I getting this error?

> file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 178 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space

```
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @return string
 */
public function hash($path)
{
    return md5_file($path);
}

/**
 * Write the contents of a file.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  string  $contents
 * @param  bool  $lock
 * @return int
 */
public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
{
    return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
}

/**
 * Prepend to a file.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  string  $data
 * @return int
 */
public function prepend($path, $data)
{
    if ($this->exists($path)) {
        return $this->put($path, $data.$this->get($path));
    }

    return $this->put($path, $data);
}

/**
 * Append to a file.
```

[image]

Comment: My first guess would be that your server is running/has run out of storage space. How many log files (roughly) do you have in `storage/logs`?

Comment: there is one log file 7.82 mb

Comment: Are there many other sites on your server?

Comment: there are many sites in total

Comment: The first thing to check is all of the log files for the sites to see if there are any that are taking up a lot of space. If there aren't any then you're going to have to either increase the storage space for your server, migrate to a bigger server and/or look at solutions to host things that do take up quite a bit of room (i.e. images, videos, user uploads etc.) like aws.

Comment: seems to have enough space

Answer (score 0):

I would try exchanging the function file_put_contents by the series of fopen, fwrite, fclose to be able to see at which point the file writing fails.

Maybe this could give us more details about the error.

Seems that this is a duplicate of this question:

[Laravel 5.1: ErrorException in file_put_contents() error,possibly out of free disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218398/laravel-5-1-errorexception-in-file-put-contents-error-possibly-out-of-free-di)

Greetings