# Laravel zombie file_put_contents exception

Tags: php, laravel, diskspace

```
$ php artisan --version                                                
Laravel Framework 5.5.32
```

My client's site has recently been displaying an ErrorException. Unfortunately, he does not know how long it has been showing up. It was pointed out to him by somebody else. In Firefox, at least, the error does not display. When one views the source, an extra body tag has been appended with all of the "Whoops!" rigamarole, and this is seen at the bottom of some browsers.

The exception itself is:

```
ErrorException: file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 184 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space in file /var/www/vhosts/prod2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 122
```

My problem is that there is no obvious reason for this disk space error.

```
$ df -h                                                                
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on                                                             
/dev/simfs       20G   11G  9.9G  51% /                                                                      
devtmpfs        512M     0  512M   0% /dev                                                                   
tmpfs           512M     0  512M   0% /dev/shm                                                               
tmpfs           512M   14M  499M   3% /run                                                                   
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock                                                              
tmpfs           512M     0  512M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup                                                         
none            512M     0  512M   0% /run/shm

$ df -i                                                                
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on                                                        
/dev/simfs     2000000 12371 1987629    1% /                                                                 
devtmpfs        131072    53  131019    1% /dev                                                              
tmpfs           131072     1  131071    1% /dev/shm                                                          
tmpfs           131072   212  130860    1% /run                                                              
tmpfs           131072     8  131064    1% /run/lock                                                         
tmpfs           131072    10  131062    1% /sys/fs/cgroup                                                    
none            131072     1  131071    1% /run/shm
```

```
config/app.php
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

config/session.php
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
```

There is no .env file. The site has no users/logins. Not even for admin.

I have triple-checked all permissions of storage and its contents. I've deleted everything within the cache, sessions, and views directories. I've restarted the webserver. I'm shift-reloading the browser. Nothing makes this exception go away.

BTW, I'm aware that it's a *very* old version of Laravel. I do not have a running arrangement for the maintenance of this site. The client has asked that I go ahead and update while I'm in here. However, I'd like to understand what's going on with this first.

EDIT: The following are commented out in Kernel.php

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

Additionally, I've set the session driver to "array" and commented out everything in config/auth.php (so that it returns an empty array).

I then emptied the views, session, and cache storage directories. I'm still seeing this stacktrace.

Comment: did you investigate the laravel log under `storage/logs/`

Comment: Does the full error stack trace give any more clues? Is it on every page, every time? Is this just plain GET requests to view pages, no forms/file uploads?  If so, sounds like it is the saving of rendered views to the cache that must be failing?  Maybe add some debug logging [at line 122](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L122) to see what is being written, and where?

Comment: The log showed nothing more than what is in the stacktrace. And it is on every page. I don't think it's anything to do with saving views. They are saving. And the disk is not out of space. The permissions are fine. It seems to be something to do with sessions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.1: ErrorException in file\_put\_contents() error,possibly out of free disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218398/laravel-5-1-errorexception-in-file-put-contents-error-possibly-out-of-free-di)